# How can I make HBase master and Region server processes bind to the public IPs?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

On using netstat on master and the region servers I can see that the master is  listening on the private ips:16000 and region servers are listening on private ip:16020 .Is there a way to force these processes to bind to the public IPs ?

Comment: If you are using Linux, edit /etc/hosts file with public ip.

Comment: Im trying to avoid changing it in /etc/hosts because other other stuff like hdfs-yarn will get messed up . Trying to look for a port redirect kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the book Hbase The Definitive Guide (I've not tried this myself):

HBase uses the local hostname to self-report its IP address. Both forward and reverse DNS resolving should work. You can verify if the setup is correct for forward DNS lookups by running the following command:

```
$ ping -c 1 $(hostname)
```

You need to make sure that it reports the public IP address of the server and not the loopback address 127.0.0.1. A typical reason for this not to work concerns an incorrect /etc/hosts file, containing a mapping of the machine name to the loopback address.
If your machine has multiple interfaces, HBase will use the interface that the primary hostname resolves to. If this is insufficient, you can set hbase.regionserver.dns.interface to indicate the primary interface. This only works if your cluster configuration is consistent and every host has the same network interface configuration.